# How to know the type of deserialized class??(or objects)

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, tcpclient, tcp

I have two classes

```
[Serializable]    
public class Class1
{                
    public List<String[]> items= new List<string[]>();        
}

[Serializable]
public class Class2
{
    public List<String[]> items = new List<string[]>();                
}
```

and I serialize these classes and send data to clients like this

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

Class1 data = new Class1(); // or Class2
data.items.Add(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"});       

bf.Serialize(memory, data);
memory.Position = 0;

byte[] buffer = memory.ToArray();                        

stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

When Client program receive data from server, the program handle the data like this

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

int bufferSize = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

memory.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
memory.Position = 0;
```

BUT in this situation, I don't know what is the type of data...Is Class1??? or Class2..

How to know the type of deserialized class??(or objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to deserialize it as an object, then use `GetType()`

`GetType(new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream));`

Comment: But GetType() only show MemoryStream. I just want to know the type of MemoryStream has

Comment: Because you haven't deserialized it into an object. Use a `new BinaryFormatter();` and call `Deserialize()` and pass your memory stream into it. Then do `GetType()` on the object.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to ensure the types of the serialized objects in the `stream`.
That is, you should define some order or protocol which would guarantee that, for example, the first object in the stream is instance of `Class1` and then goes instance of `Class2`.

Doing so, you can do it more or less controllable: having deserialized instance of `Class1` from the stream, you may decide what object should be next in the stream depending on the data in `Class1` object.

The other solution is to wrap objects of `Class1` and `Class2` into some container class and just serialize objects of that container.
It will do if you need to serialize objects of the same type every time.

But if you only need to check the type then, having deserialized any object from the stream, you can check its type by `is`-check, by comparing its type token or by safe cast. See the example:

```
object d = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
Class1 c1 = null;
if ((c1 = d as Class1) != null) {
    //do something with c1
}
```

Comment: Or he could just check if the deserialized object is of type Class1 or Class2.

Comment: But yes, I agree fully with you, he should try to avoid a serialized stream containing "an unknown quantity and type of objects".

Answer (score 0):

I offer add a byte into head of bytes array deserialized from object and in server you only have to check the first byte to know what Class of that buffer. This will make server performance.

```
switch(buffer[0])
{
    case DataType.NORMAL:
    ...
    break;
    case DataType.FILE_TRANSFER:
    ...
    break;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I would suggest 2 bytes. http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/effective-tcp.html

Comment: Based on question, I think only need one byte, if he want more info, he can add more bytes